# what does bake do in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

What is the purpose of "bake" option in SceneKit editor. Does it have an impact on performance?
[image]

Type offers 2 options: Ambient Occlusion and Light Map

Destination offers: Texture and Vertex

Answer (score 3):

For me, it crashes Xcode. It's supposed to render lighting (specifically shadows) into the textures on objects so you don't need static lights.

This should, theoretically, mean that all you need in your scene are the lights used to create dynamic lighting on objects that move, and you can save all the calculations required to fill the scene with static lights on static geometry.

In terms of performance, yes, baking in the lighting can create a HUGE jump in performance because it's saving you all the complex calculations that create ambient light, occlusion and direct shadows and soft shadows.

If you're using ambient occlusion and soft shadows in real-time you'll be seeing VERY low frame rates.

And the quality possible with baking is far beyond what you can achieve with a super computer in real time, particularly in terms of global illumination.

What's odd is that Scene Kit has a bake button. It has never worked for me, always crashing Xcode. But the thing is... to get the most from baking, you need to be a 3D artist, in which case you'll be much more inclined to do the baking in a 3D design app.

And 3D design apps have lighting solutions that are orders of magnitude better than the best Scene Kit lighting possible. I can't imagine that there's really a need for baking in Scene Kit. It's a strange thing for the development team to have spent time on as it simply could never come close to the quality afforded by even the cheapest 3D design app.

Comment: I realise this thread is a year old, but in case anyone is reading and wondering, the SceneKit editor is way more stable in Xcode 8.1 than in 7, and the bake button works very nicely now. You need to have at least one light with its mode set to "static" for shadow baking to work (an error message warns you if you have no static lights).

Comment: I'll give it a try, one of these days. Be curious as to whether they used it to do their lightmaps in the cart demo.

Answer (score 2):

What I remember from college days:
Baking is actually process in 3D rendering and textures. You have two kind of bakings: texture baking and physics baking.

Texture baking:
You calculate some data and save that data to a texture. You use that on your material. With that, you reduce rendering time. Every single frame, everything is calculated again and again. If you have animations, that is a lot of time wasted there.

Physics baking:
You can pre calculate physics simulations exactly like above baking and you use that data. For example you use it in Rigid Body.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. SceneKit offers Vertex baking, which is probably Physics baking. I am now running Light Map baking. I can hear that computer really has hard time doing it.

Comment: So should I expect drastic performance increase after baking every single object in my 3D scene?

Comment: You can only bake lighting which is not going to need to change, or it will be incorrect as soon as anything moves.

Comment: You can bake to texture and vertices. When you bake to textures a file is created called light map. This map contains textures, materials, illumination... When baking to vertices, data is created and and stored in mesh's vertex colours. You have couple of vertex maps: in the vertex, RGB and alpha are stored for colour calculation. Second is displacement: X, Y, Z coordinates of the vertex changes: sample contains RGBA, luminance is used for colour. Don't bake everything you have, you need to determine when you need baking.

Comment: I have an ambient and spot light. Both of them are not moving. They shine on blue SCNFloor among other objects. The floor is not moving too, therefore baking is an option. Whenever I bake light map on floor object, it loses its color and takes over the color of the light. It goes from blue to gray(gray is the color of my lights because white is too bright.) Also all colisions stop working which is kinda weird. What have I missed?

Comment: I realize this thread was last updated in 2015 but... @potato did you ever try baking a texture map then checking the Materials>Property>Diffuse list for a freshly baked image map map? I'm guessing the model preview turns gray because the current diffuse map has been deselected due to a new texture map being rendered.

Comment: @Flipper could you elaborate?  Coding examples or links to Apple docs on vertex displacement X, Y, Z coordinates would help.  I was unable to find documentation on this.