# How does baking in the SceneKit editor work?

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

In the SceneKit editor there's an option to bake the ambient occlusion. I've opened a model and clicked the bake button, but nothing is happening. The appearance of the object stays the same. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Xcode 9.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does bake do in SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568786/what-does-bake-do-in-scenekit)

Comment: @the4kman This doesn't explain why nothing is happening when I bake the ambient occlusion.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your model is very complex (a few hundred thousand polygons) and the baking is running in the background, somehow failing or taking a long time. I sometimes did not get a message in Xcode that baking is running. You can look for a com.apple.dt.IDESceneKitEditor.Bakery process in activity monitor to see if it's doing anything.